# Validation without regex

Tags: javascript

how to validate alphanumeric and date formats without using regex and any other framework.Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you want to use RegEx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Date.parse()` to test date strings.  As for testing alpha-numeric strings without regex, write a loop to go through the characters of the strings to see of a character is there that shouldn't be.